# Devolver lista desde la vista al controlador con los registros seleccionados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Envío una lista desde el controlador a la vista y necesito devolver la lista con los registros seleccionados y la lista llega vacía con 0 registros.
Aquí coloco el código, el método recibe la lista vacía.

Método del controlador que debe recibir la lista desde la vista.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(List<Carro> ListaCarros)
    {
       foreach (var item in ListaCarros)
       {
            //Código
       }
       return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Esta es la vista que muestra la lista.

```
@model IEnumerable<ListaVistaControlador.Models.Carro>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lista de Carros";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Lista Carros</h3>

<form method="post">
    <div>
            <table class="table table-striped border">
                <tr>
                    <th>Seleccionar</th>
                    <th>Marca</th>
                    <th>Modelo</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var carro in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@carro.Seleccionar" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carro.Marca)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carro.Modelo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carro.Color)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <div class="col-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Enviar lista</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Agradezco si me pueden colaborar.

Comment: Hola, probaste recibir la Lista en tu vista como model List<ListaVistaControlador.Models.Carro> y no como model IEnumerable<ListaVistaControlador.Models.Carro> ya que lo que recibes en tu controlador es un list, no lo he probado pero tal vez ayude

Comment: Gracias por responder, cambie
model IEnumerable<ListaVistaControlador.Models.Carro> por
model List<ListaVistaControlador.Models.Carro> y sigue sin llegando la vista vacia

Comment: Publica la clase `Carro`